# How to stop AOSP from loading .so from vendor image

Tags: android, c++, android-source

AOSP (android 8.0.0-r3) for Pixel XL, Im trying to stop Android from loading `nfc_nci.marlin.so` by

- removed `nfc_nci.marlin` from `device-marlin.mk`
- removed the source from `system/nfc/halimpl/pn54x`

After rebuild and flash to phone, I still notice from logcat :

> sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading
>   /vendor/lib64/hw/nfc_nci.marlin.so from the current namespace instead.

Since I did not build `nfc_nci.marlin.so`, I did a search and found a hit in `vendor/google_devices/marlin/proprietary/vendor.img`. How can I stop the AOSP from loading this share library from vendor image??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you have the same device tree as me, but you have to remove `nfc_nci.marlin.so` from `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES` in `vendor/google/devices/marlin/marlin-vendor-blobs.mk`, then manually from `out(..)/vendor/lib(,64)/hw/` and rebuild the AOSP

Comment: there is no `marlin-vendor-blobs.mk` , I searched the whole vendor/ dir and there are no files containing `nfc_nci.marlin.so`, only found a hit in `vendor/google_devices/marlin/proprietary/vendor.img`

Comment: Then mount that image and remove that file from filesystem eg.
`mount -orw vendor/google_devices/marlin/proprietary/vendor.img /mnt/test`
Don't forget unmount after such operation